# VBA - Store 2 values in the same index of a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a worksheet with a defined range on the XY plane with cells filled with color within its limits.

I have to move across that range and store each filled cell address in an array `(x,Y)`, then assign a unique "speed vector" to each of these cells `(dY, dX)`, so at the end of the loop of going through the whole range, each cell has 4 unique values: `x, Y, dx, dY`.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
Dim Molecules() As Variant
  ReDim Molecules(1 To lWidth, 1 To lHeight) 'lWidth and lHeight indicate a dynamic range

 Dim Vector() As Variant
   ReDim Vector(1 To lMolecules, 1 To lMolecules) 'lMolecules is the number of filled cells within limits

  For x = LBound(Molecules) To UBound(Molecules)    'columns (x)
    For Y = LBound(Molecules, 2) To UBound(Molecules, 2)    'rows (y)
      If Cells(Y, x).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
       'store each filled cell address in an array               
         Molecules(Y, x) = Cells(Y, x).Address
          MsgBox "the address of original cells is = " & Molecules(Y, x)

       Randomize
        'between (-5) and (5) which are the H and L values
          dX = Int((H - L + 1) * Rnd() + L) 'speed vector x
           dY = Int((H - L + 1) * Rnd() + L) 'speed vector y

      'store the dX and dY values in an array
         Vector(Y, x) = (dY, dX)
           MsgBox "the speed vector is = " & Vector(Y, x)
```

I was able to store the address of the `Cells(Y,x)`, here:

```
Molecules(Y, x) = Cells(Y, x).Address
```

However, I could not get to store the values of `(dY, dx)` no matter which method I used: `Offset // Address // Cells` in that part:

```
'store the dX and dY values in an array
         Vector(Y, x) = (dY, dX)
```

Is there an actual way to do that, or do I need to store the random values in a sheet and assign/insert those sheet cell values back into the array?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Will they correspond?  array Molecules is Height & Width, where Vector is the number of filled cells, this could be Molecules(100,100) & vector(1,1)

Comment: You can use a simple `Type` with attributes dX and dY, and store that in your 2D array.  Or just do `Vector(Y, x) = Array(dX, dY)`

Comment: @Tim Williams: Thank you, it now indeed stores the values in the array. However, I could not get the Vector(Y,x) index to Msgbox the values - is there any way to define the Msgbox expression so that I could actually witness the inserting?

Comment: @Tim Williams: Thank you again, everything works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Molecules() As Variant
  ReDim Molecules(1 To lWidth, 1 To lHeight) 'lWidth and lHeight indicate a dynamic range

 Dim Vector() As Variant
   ReDim Vector(1 To lMolecules, 1 To lMolecules) 'lMolecules is the number of filled cells within limits

  For x = LBound(Molecules) To UBound(Molecules)    'columns (x)
    For Y = LBound(Molecules, 2) To UBound(Molecules, 2)    'rows (y)
      If Cells(Y, x).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
       'store each filled cell address in an array               
         Molecules(Y, x) = Cells(Y, x).Address
          MsgBox "the address of original cells is = " & Molecules(Y, x)

       Randomize
        'between (-5) and (5) which are the H and L values
          dX = Int((H - L + 1) * Rnd() + L) 'speed vector x
           dY = Int((H - L + 1) * Rnd() + L) 'speed vector y

      'store the dX and dY values in an array
         Vector(Y, x) = Array(dY, dX) '<<< store as array
           MsgBox "The speed vector is = " & Vector(Y, x)(0) & _
                     ":" & Vector(Y, x)(1)
```